# jQuery replace() flickers in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

I have a script where following code is executed on mousemove to restart a css animation:

`var $clone = $(this).clone(true, true);
$(this).replaceWith($clone);`

This works smooth in all browsers, except Safari for Mac where it flickers while replacing.

Do you have any ideas how to avoid this issue?